# Invariant Violation: View config not found for name p

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display key and value pairs from the array...

But I am getting the following error.

> Device: (17:404) Invariant Violation: View config not found for name p

[image]

Do I need to import any package?
Please suggest...

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        data:[
          {id:1, name:'michel'},
          {id:2, name:'ddd'},
          {id:3, name:'ee'}               
        ]
      }
    }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
    { 
      this.state.data.map((dynamicData) =>
      <p>{dynamicData.name}</p>)
    }
    </div>
    ) 
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Are you using react-native? Because those DOM elements are not supposed to be used within native.

Comment: yes i am using react native

Comment: That is the problem, you should not use `<div>`, rather use `<View>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using React native, HTML elements don't exist. You should be using the [basic components](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/components-and-apis.html#basic-components) that it provides.

```
return (
    <View>
        this.state.data.map((dynamicData) =>
            <Text>{dynamicData.name}</Text>
        )
    </View>
);
```

Comment: yes i am using react native ...

ESLint: (33:16) 'dynamicData' is not defined. (no-undef)